# Replace folder name with characters in parentheses

Tags: powershell

I have multiple folders named like: `FirstName_LastName(12345)`

I would like to remove everything except the parentheses  to give `12345`.

I thought this would work, but it says the regular expression pattern `*(*)` is not valid.

`Get-ChildItem '*(*)' | Rename-Item -newname { $_.name -Replace '*(*)','*' }`

I'm using Windows PowerShell.

Comment: This command alone `Get-ChildItem '*(*)'` works?

Comment: Yes, if I name those items it returns the correct items.

Comment: `$_.Name -replace '.*\((.*)\)','$1'`

Comment: Thank you! This has been bugging me for some time! If you post this as an answer I'll set it as my accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-replace` takes a regex pattern as its argument, and in regex, `*` is a quantifier meaning "0 or more". You'll also need to escape the `()`:

```
Get-ChildItem '*(*)' | Rename-Item -newname { $_.name -Replace '.*\((.*)\)','$1' }
```

`$1` is a backreference to the first capture group, ie. whatever was matched by `.*` in the `(.*)` part of the pattern